# Can Blazor get input text value without binding?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

It seems that all the examples in the search result are using binding, updating the bound variable oninput. Is this the only approved way other than using external JavaScript? I mean, if I have assigned a `@ref`, can't I get the current value using the @ref variable, hypothetically like

```
<input type="text" @ref="myinputbox" />
....
string value = myinputbox.Value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is another way.  If you type and hover `@onchange` event, you can see the expected signature of the event handler, which accepts `ChangeEventArgs`, which exposes the `Value` of the arguments-- in this case, a string with the new contents after a change is made.  So:

```
<input @onchange=HandleChange />
<div>@DisplayMessage</div>

@code {
    string DisplayMessage = "";
    async Task HandleChange (ChangeEventArgs args){
        DisplayMessage = args.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my intention was not clear; I meant getting the text string using the @ref variable at any arbitrary time, not tracking the value at some event handler. The very reason why I tried not to use binding was not using any events like `onXXX` to keep updating a variable. If you say keep updating the value at a modification event is the only way, I will that that as the answer.

Comment: In Benny's code above, if you link `HandleChange` into the `@oninput` instead of `@onchange` then `DisplayMessage` is updated on each keystroke.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The only problem I have with oft-triggered events like that is that if you have high latency (say with an international client), their experience may not match what you see in development.

Comment: @Damn Vegetables, you can get the value whenever you want.  But if you want an updated value, the client browser has to collect keystrokes and send the change info to the server in some form or another.  The same thing even happens just in Windows (or any other OS)-- you have a keyboard input buffer etc. between you and a File Browser input when you're typing a file name or whatever.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973.  For high latency clients you could build a debouncer on the JS side, using say the standard timer technique, to only raise a custom event with the same signature as oninput, when the user stops typing.  With High latency clients you also need to consider kicking `ComponentBase` into touch and taking greater control over the render process.

Comment: "consider kicking`ComponentBase into touch`" sounds like British English to me.  What does it mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `@ref` like this:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<input type="text" @oninput=OnChange @ref="element" />

@code {
    private ElementReference element;

    private string? value;

    void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this.value = e.Value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

But what you are referencing is not a `component`, but an html element. `ElementReference` only contains a Guid that is used by the built in JS interop code and can be be used to reference the element in custom JS interops you write.  Put a break in on `this.value=...` and look at `element`.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you would like to access the value "at any arbitrary time."  If you go ahead and bind the value to a private variable, you can access the value any time you want.

In my case, the values being collected were in a modal.  I didn't want the values of the model updated until the user clicked "OK".

```
<input type="text" @bind="_firstName" />
<button type="submit" @onclick="Save">OK</button>
...

[Parameter]
public ProfileModel Model { get; set; }
private string _firstName;
...

private void Save()
{
    Model.FirstName = _firstName;
}
```